# Piranha cms paging

Tags: piranha-cms

Is there anyone using Piranha as base framework to develop your site? I'm having an issue with paging the content in the Manager mode. I have a look at the core and it seems that there is no paging functionality for any content, Page, Post, setting. It will be a big problem when our site grow and more content has been added. Anyone know where should I have a look or how can I implement a paging functionality for Piranha?

Answer (score 1):

This just one of these functions that have not been prioritized. I suggest you create an issue for it at GitHub so we can discuss it as functionality will differ depending on the type of entity.

Pages & media are hierarchical while posts are flat. Post are however split into tabs depending on post type which kind of filters it down.

The search functionality will also have to be altered as it currently uses listjs and searches the DOM.

Looking forward to your issue at GitHub!

Regards

Håkan